# how to add points on slider bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I want to create slider, which divides to 5 equal part. I want to put a little circle on the dividers' part! like image bellow
[image: my slider bar]
and another thing I want to do in to move my thumb above the slider sho when my thumbs moves, it stop on the point on the main slider. how can I achieve this?!

**what I have done:**

I've tried to use a stackview with circle in it and equal spacing, and put it on the slider, but after that, my slider won't work, because the stack have a higher priority! for changing the thumb location, I was out of option and tried to use an image , and bellow this image, is a transparent space!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It's never a good idea to get somebody to write a block of code for you if you haven't tried anything, so in the future try to include some of your own work on the problem.

Comment: @JaredH I've explained in my edit

Comment: @GabeSpound I've explained in my edit! I asked this question because I was out of option and didn't know what to write!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave it a try and found this solution even if it might not be the most elegant one.

For the snappy behaviour you are looking for, you can define an IBAction for your slider (on touch up inside event).

In this action get the current value, round it up and set the slider to this new value.

```
@IBAction func finishTouching(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let currentValue = slider.value
    let roundedValue = currentValue.rounded()
    slider.setValue(roundedValue, animated: true)
}
```

For the other part regarding the design you try to achieve you might just try to switch the user interaction enabled to off (false) on your stackview or image. That will make you slider underneath to respond to touch event again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I switched off interaction and I achieve to my design! about the thumb change, your answer was working! I also tested a way, which was an IBAction on value change! and the rest of it was the same as your solution! both of them worked! thanks